# Can I show a video from web player to android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I want to ask, is it possible to display a video from a web player which is usually displayed using an iframe on the website?

my boss told me to make an application like that,
an example of a video using this

```
https://vanfem.com/v/8qqlyh8lmxgkn5y
```

is that possible? is it also possible to use that url in [exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add gradle dependency in `app/build.gradle`

   ```
   dependencies { 
       implementation project(":exoplayer-codelab-00")
   }
   ```
2. Open the build.gradle file of the exoplayer-codelab-00 module. 
   Add the following lines to the dependencies section and sync the project.

   ```
   def mediaVersion = "1.0.0-alpha03"
   dependencies {
       [...]

       implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:$mediaVersion"
       implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:$mediaVersion"
       implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:$mediaVersion"
   }
   ```
3. Open the layout resource file `activity_player.xml` from the exoplayer-`codelab-00 module`.

   ```
   <androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
      android:id="@+id/video_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   ```
4. In PlayerActivity.kt

   ```
   private var player: ExoPlayer? = null
   private fun initializePlayer() {
      player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
      .build()
      .also { exoPlayer ->
        viewBinding.videoView.player = exoPlayer
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("https://vanfem.com/v/8qqlyh8lmxgkn5y"))
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
        exoPlayer.seekTo(currentItem, playbackPosition)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
      }
   }

   public override fun onStart() {
      super.onStart()
      if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
         initializePlayer()
      }
    }

   public override fun onStop() {
      super.onStop()
      if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
         releasePlayer()
      }
   }

   private fun releasePlayer() {
      player?.let { exoPlayer ->
         playbackPosition = exoPlayer.currentPosition
         currentItem = exoPlayer.currentMediaItemIndex
         playWhenReady = exoPlayer.playWhenReady
         exoPlayer.release()
      }
     player = null
   }
   ```
5. for more details you can study this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#0) and [github](https://github.com/androidx/media)

Comment: thanks for answering, I'll try it, later if there is a problem may I ask?